# Question on symmetric difference and measurability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The following is a homework problem for Analysis

Let $\mu$ be an outer measure on $X$. Assume that a subset $A$ of $X$ has the property that for each $ε> 0$, there exists a measurable set $E$ such that $μ(A△E) < ε$. Show that A is also measurable.

So for any $F \in X$

I tried to get an inequality of the form

$\mu(F) \ge \mu(F \bigcap A) + \mu(F -A) -\epsilon $

and to use a corresponding $E$ to get this but I am not sure how to proceed

Any hints are appreciated 
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove $\mu(F\cap A)+\mu(F\cap A^c)\leq \mu(F)$. Note that for any set $E$, we have $F\cap A = (F\cap A)\cap E\cup (F\cap A)\cap E^c$. Choose $\epsilon>0$, and $E$ such that $\mu(A\Delta E)<\epsilon/2$. Then we have \begin{align}\mu(F\cap A)+\mu(F\cap A^c)&\leq \mu(F\cap A\cap E)+\mu(F\cap A\cap E^c)+\mu(F\cap A^c\cap E)+\mu(F\cap A^c\cap E^c)\\&\leq \mu(F\cap E)+\mu(A\cap E^c)+\mu(A^c\cap E)+\mu(F\cap E^c)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)\\&=\mu(F)+\mu(A\cap E^c)+\mu(A^c\cap E)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,(2)\\&\leq\mu(F)+\mu((A\cap E^c)\cup (A^c\cap E))+\mu((A^c\cap E)\cup(A\cap E^c)\;\;\;\;\,(3)\\&=\mu(F)+2\mu(A\Delta E)\leq \mu(F)+\epsilon\end{align}$(1)$ and $(3)$ follow from monotonicity, and $(2)$ follows because $E$ is measurable. Because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\mu(F\cap A)+\mu(F\cap A^c)\leq \mu(F)$